# Confusion regarding interval of a variable.

Tags: functions, derivatives, inequality

**Question:**

> The values of '$a$' if $f(x)=2e^x-ae^{-x}+(2a+1)x-3$ increases $\forall \;x \in \mathbb R$ are:
>
> $(A)\;[0,\infty) \qquad(B)\;(-\infty,0] \qquad(C)\;(-\infty,\infty)\quad(D)\;(1,\infty)$
>
> > **Answer:** A

**Doubt:**

As it is given in the question, $f(x)$ is increasing.

$\implies f'(x)>0$

On simplifying $f'(x)>0$ a little, I finally got: $$e^x+a>0 \quad\forall\;x\in \mathbb R$$

which according to me should give $a \in (0,\infty)$, because when $a=0$, then we get $e^x>0$, but on keeping $x=-\infty$, this inequation is not satisfied.

But on putting $a=0$ in $f(x)$, I am getting $f'(x)>0$, which means that the function is increasing when $a=0$ and the answer given is correct.

Kindly explain why $0$ will be included in the interval of $a$.

Comment: Is $-\infty \in \mathbb R$? Alternatively, examine the graph of $e^x$. Is there any point where the graph touches the horizontal axis exactly?

Comment: $\mathbb R = (-\infty , \infty)$ .

Comment: Actually, we can't really blame you for not knowing that $\infty\notin\Bbb R$ since $\Bbb R$ is rarely properly defined in "basic" courses.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know till now that $\infty$ doesn't belong to R. The graph of $e^x$ doesn't touch the x axis anywhere but we generally take $\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}=0$

Comment: As $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ is decreasing, $x\mapsto - a e^{-x}$ is increasing whenever $a\geq 0$. The sum of increasing functions is increasing (easily checked) and thus the set of acceptable $a$'s contains at least $[0,\infty)$. Now, try to prove that for any $a<0$, this will not be increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repeat my comment and give a complete proof inspired by [Salah Fatima's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2066112/283812) (which is not complete).

In my comment, I say that as $x\mapsto e^{x}$ and $x\mapsto x$ are increasing functions, we know that it is also the case for $x\mapsto \alpha e^{x}+\beta x$ for any $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$. Similarly, as $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ is decreasing, $x\mapsto \gamma e^{-x}$ is increasing whenever $\gamma <0$ (this is easy to see). Thus, if we take $a\in[0,\infty)$, we know that $(2a+1)\geq 0$ and $-a<0$, thus for these $a$'s, the function

$$f:x\mapsto 2e^{x}-ae^{-x}+(2a+1)x-3$$

is increasing. This restricts the possible answers to $(A)$ and $(C)$.

Now, we could prove that it is decreasing when $a<0$. But the idea (and yours) of Salah Fatima seems better, since finding for which value of $a$ the derivative is positive or $0$ gives us the answer, as the derivative caracterizes the tonicity of a function and is a priori easier to compute.

We have $f'(x)=2e^{x}+ae^{-x}+(2a+1)$. As pointed out by Salah Fatima, this can be factorized in $f'(x)=e^{-x}(2e^{2x}+(2a+1)e^{x}+a)$ and as $e^{-x}>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, it is sufficient to look for $a$ such that $2e^{2x}+(2a+1)e^{x}+a\geq 0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Let's pose $t=e^{x}$. We have $g(t):=2t^{2}+(2a+1)t+a$ with $t>0$. We know that a quadratic function such as $t\mapsto g(t)$ has the same sign as the coefficient of $t^{2}$ except between the roots. Here, we have $g(t)\geq 0$ when $t>0$ if and only if the two roots are inferior to $0$ or if it has no real roots. Computing the discriminant yields $\Delta = (2a+1)^{2}-8a=(2a-1)^2\geq 0$. Thus, $g(t)$ has always two roots (possibly equal). These roots are :

\begin{align*}
\alpha_{+} &= \frac{-(2a+1)+\vert 2a -1\vert}{4}\\
\alpha_{-} &= \frac{-(2a+1)-\vert 2a-1\vert}{4}
\end{align*}

We know that they have to be less than $0$ for $g$ to be positive everywhere for $t>0$ and thus for $f$ to be increasing. We also know that it works when $a\geq 0$ because of our initial reasoning, so we only have to check $a<0$. Suppose $a<0$. Then, $\vert 2a-1\vert = -2a+1$. Hence,

$$\alpha_{+}\le 0\iff -2a-1-2a+1\le 0\iff -4a \le 0$$

But as $a<0$, this is not possible. Hence, $\alpha_{+}$ has to be strictly positive. We deduce that $a<0$ yields a non-increasing function. Hence, $(A)$ is valid and $(C)$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is

$$f'(x)=e^{-x}(2e^{2x}+(2a+1)e^x+a)$$

is positive for all $x\in \Bbb R$ if the discriminant is negative.

$$\Delta=4a^2+1+4a-8a=(2a-1)^2\leq 0$$

$$\iff a=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: This does not prove anything but the idea is interesting. I have formulated a complete answer below. Correct me if I made a wrong reasoning but I think you didn't take into account the fact that $e^{x}$ is always positive.