# Find the set of values of $a$ if $f(x)=2e^x-ae^{-x}+(2a+1)x-3$ increases $\forall\;x$

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function, roots

> Find the set of values of $a$ if $f(x)=2e^x-ae^{-x}+(2a+1)x-3$ increases $\forall\;x$

This question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066081/confusion-regarding-interval-of-a-variable)

My doubt is regarding @hamam_Abdallah's answer there. Why is that method giving wrong result? (I had also solved exactly like that).

@MoebiusCorzer in the comment says the fact that $e^x$ is positive has not been considered. I wonder how this fact will help improve that method.

Comment: Since $e^x \geq 0$, one has to find the $a$'s such that $2X^2  + (2a+1)X+a$ takes positive values on $[0,+\infty)$. The given answer only looks at the $a$'s such that $2X^2  + (2a+1)X+a$ takes positive values on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with that answer is that it finds a sufficient, but not necessary, condition for $f'(x) = e^{-x}(2e^{2x}+(2a+1)e^x+a) \ge 0$. He finds $a$ such that $2x^2 + (2a+1)x+a\ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, which will of course guarantee $f'(x) \ge 0$. The problem is that $e^x$ does not take on every value of $\mathbb R$--only the positive ones--so there are other values of $a$ where $2x^2 + (2a+1)x+a$ is negative for some $x < 0$ but positive for all $x > 0$. These will also give $f'(x) \ge 0$, and thus are also solutions to the problem.

Since only being negative when $x < 0$ requires there to be no positive zeroes, and $2x^2 + (2a+1)x + a = (2x+1)(x+a)$, we see that we must have $a \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $f'(x)$ to be always non-negative we need $2e^{2x}+(2a+1)e^x+a$ to be always non-negative. Let $e^x=t$, then we need $2t^2+(2a+1)t+a$ to be positive for all $t>0$, which is not the same as being non-negative for all real $t$. For this quadratic polynomial to be non-negative for all positive $t$ one needs $$(2a+1)^2-8a \leq 0 \lor (-\frac{2a+1}{4}\leq 0 \land a\geq 0)$$
$$4a^2-4a+1\leq 0 \lor (2a\geq -1 \land a\geq 0)$$
$$a=\frac{1}{2} \lor a\geq 0$$
$$a\geq 0$$

Comment: that's a very cute solution, thanks.